# Have a matrix dot its transpose, what is the original matrix?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, matrix-decomposition

I have a matrix that equals the dot product of a matrix A with its transpose. How do I get the matrix A?

Ex.:  $AA^T$ = [a given matrix]

Comment: In general there will be multiple solutions.  That is so say, one cannot uniquely recover $A$ from the given data.  Even in the case of $1\times1$ matrices.

Comment: You can't. If you have symmetric $B$ also positive definite, it can be written as $B = C C^T.$ However, given any orthogonal $P,$ meaning $PP^T = P^T P = I,$ we also have $B = (CP)(CP)^T$

Answer (score 1):

In general, you can't. For example,
$$[1\ 8]\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 8\end{pmatrix} = [4\ 7]\begin{pmatrix}4 \\ 7\end{pmatrix} = [65].$$